# How to use Ant properties to allow copying cross projects

Tags: ant, copy, perforce, move

I have 2 projects with perforce as versioning system and ant for builds.

I have an ant build script in one of the project and I am trying to copy files between the 2 projects when ant is executed.

I tried Ant copy using relative path but it always look under the "." so I think the only way now is to use the Ant properties to set up a path to the other projects.

If I hardcoded absolute path it works for me however it wouldn't work for my peers because they have different paths to their perforce workspace.

How should I solve this problem ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify properties on the command line with

```
-Dname=value
```

i.e.

```
ant -DotherProjectRoot=C:\foo
```

This value can then be accessed in the ant build file like a self defined property.

```
<copy todir="${otherProjectRoot}">
    ...
</copy>
```

As this is quite cumbersome, you could define the property in a separate file:

```
<property file="user.properties"/>
```

with the file containing e.g.

```
otherProjectRoot=C:\foo
```

Your colleagues would then have to modifiy this file on their machines pointing to the appropriate workspace / directory.